# obscure Unix find command syntax understanding

Tags: unix, find

Need help in understanding this complex Unix **find** command and its operation:

```
find . \( \! -user xx -exec chown -- xx '{}' + -false \) -o    \
\( \! -group root -exec chgrp -- root '{}' + \) -o \
\( ! -perm 700 -exec chmod -- 700 '{}' + -exec false \; \)
```

Also, I am looking out in particular the purpose of **-false** predicate. I guess I mixed both GNU and non-GNU **find** syntax

Answer (score 3):

The false predicate evaluated to false for `-o` and it is used here to prevent short short-circuiting.

- if user is not xx make it xx
- if group is not root, make it root
- if not all permissions are set for the owner, grant all permissions.

Each command is separated by `-o` and terminated by `false` so that they are ALL applied to each item.

Comment: Thank you [perreal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/390913/perreal), but still I could not understand the purpose of **-false** and its meaning of short-circuiting. What if I dont use it in the above code? Also, the option "-o" just concatenates each individual command here? if so, what **-or** and **-a** is for?

Comment: Since or, as a logical operator, evaluates to true if any of it's arguments are true, most programming languages stop evaluation and return true (which is called short circuiting). In order to prevent this, you can force each argument to return `false` and hence evaluate all `or`'ed terms.

Comment: In that case we could use option **-a** (AND) instead of **-o** (OR) which will strictly evaluate all without the purpose of short circuiting (**-false**)?? Also, I hope options **-o** and **-or** are one and the same in **find** command

Comment: And will short circuit also, so you will have to do `true` instead. And yes, `-o` is `-or`.