# What is the purpose of find's "false" option?

Tags: linux, unix, command

According to `man find`

> -false Always false.

What is the purpose of this option?
When is it used?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/q/21525727/3220113 explains something.

Comment: added example in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36522667/5832518) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`false` and `true` options will be used with complex test expressions in `find`  command.

---

### [gnu documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Finding-Files):

`find` evaluates the expression each time it processes a file. An expression can contain any of the following types of primaries:

1. *options*

   affect overall operation rather than the processing of a specific file;
2. *tests*

   return a true or false value, depending on the file's attributes;
3. *actions*

   have side effects and return a true or false value; and
4. *operators*

   connect the other arguments and affect when and whether they are evaluated.

#### [Combining Primaries With Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Combining-Primaries-With-Operators)

Operators build a complex expression from tests and actions. The operators are, in order of decreasing precedence:

```
( expr )
    Force precedence. True if expr is true.
! expr
-not expr
    True if expr is false. In some shells, it is necessary to protect 
    the ‘!’ from shell interpretation by quoting it.
expr1 expr2
expr1 -a expr2
expr1 -and expr2
    And; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is false.
expr1 -o expr2
expr1 -or expr2
    Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.
expr1 , expr2
    List; both expr1 and expr2 are always evaluated. 
    True if expr2 is true. The value of expr1 is discarded. 
    This operator lets you do multiple independent operations on one 
    traversal, without depending on whether other operations succeeded. 
    The two operations expr1 and expr2 are not always fully independent,
     since expr1 might have side effects like touching or deleting files,
     or it might use ‘-prune’ which would also affect expr2. 
— Test: -true  
    Always true. 
— Test: -false
    Always false.
```

find searches the directory tree rooted at each file name by evaluating the expression from left to right, according to the rules of precedence, until the outcome is known (the left hand side is false for ‘-and’, true for ‘-or’), at which point find moves on to the next file name.

#### Example : [source question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525727/obscure-unix-find-command-syntax-understanding)

```
find . \( \! -user xx -exec chown -- xx '{}' + -false \) -o    \
\( \! -group root -exec chgrp -- root '{}' + \) -o \
\( ! -perm 700 -exec chmod -- 700 '{}' + -exec false \; \)
```

**Explanation:** ( by [perreal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21526751/5832518))

The false predicate evaluated to false for -o and it is used here to prevent short short-circuiting.

```
if user is not xx make it xx
if group is not root, make it root
if not all permissions are set for the owner, grant all permissions.
```

Each command is separated by -o and terminated by false so that they are ALL applied to each item.

**what is the purpose of `false` in above command ?**

`or` as a logical operator, evaluates to true if any of it's arguments are true, most programming languages stop evaluation and return true (which is called short circuiting). In order to prevent this, you can force each argument to return `false` and hence evaluate all `or`'ed terms.

Comment: The challenge to actually find a valid use case :)

Comment: @isedev, you are correct .... unfortunately my machine has too old version of `find`(can't update due to restrictions). It doesn't support above test options. :(

Comment: Thanks. I understand the example. It's strange to me to require that ugly `-false` everywhere - feels kind of hacky. You really can't have multiple `if` statements without doing that?

Comment: The same find command can be achieved with multilple lines of shell script. But, just by using `find` command alone, it's not possible to put `if` control. Because `find` [does not have](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) an `if` option.